# Dates manipulations in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have datetime column which has data like: 2013-04-19 23:44:27.357

In *iReport* I'm using expression `new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma").format($F{domain_datetime})` to display only the time.

In the expression above I'd like to say if time greater then 23:59 then instead of displaying time I want to display a day, for example 5 MAR 13, otherwise display a time.

How to do it?

Comment: So are you saying if the date is `2013-04-19 23:59:27.357` it should formatted to `19 MAR 13` or should that be `11:59PM`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are are don't care about the information beyond seconds, and simply want to convert anything that would format to  `12:00AM` the day you could replace your current expression with:

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma").format($F{domain_datetime}).equals("12:00AM")) ? 
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy").format($F{domain_datetime}) : 
new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma").format($F{domain_datetime})
```

Now this works, but it creates 3 new `SimpleDateFormat` instances for the expression, when only 2 or needed (I would also be curious to know if it would create 3 new `SimpleDateFormat` objects for each row, but I don't know if that is the case). So in my eyes this can be improved some.

Create two new Parameters in your report that will be `SimpleDateFormat` instances. The XML for them should look like:

```
<parameter name="TIME_FORMAT" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="DATE_FORMAT" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

They have default values for the date formatter, and we can reference them in our expression. So now we can rewrite our expression to be:

```
($P{TIME_FORMAT}.format($F{domain_datetime}).equals("12:00AM")) ? 
$P{DATE_FORMAT}.format($F{domain_datetime}) : 
$P{TIME_FORMAT}.format($F{domain_datetime})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it on the query used to fill up the report or in Java if your are using a JRBeanCollectionDataSource? That way you only need to show a text no matter what is it